# Perl regex not-match-strings operation

Tags: regex, perl

**What I have so far:**

Here is the regex I created

```
 if ( /PRINT\((\s*\n*\t*)[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*(_*)(DBG|NOT|UNC)/  ) { next; }
```

Currently it executes `next`when it detects

```
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_DBG...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_NOT...
PRINT(ABC_UNC...
```

and it doesn't execute `next` when it is

```
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_ERR...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_WRN...
PRINT(ABC_ERR...
```

**I want to change it to:**

I want to modify it so it will execute `next` for everything other than `_ERR` or `_WRN`

```
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_ERR...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_WRN...
PRINT(ABC_ERR...
```

I tried the following but it didn't match anything

```
        my $ERR = qr/ERR/;
        my $WRN = qr/WRN/;
 if ( /PRINT\((\s*\n*\t*)[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*(_*)(?!$ERR|$WRN)/  ) { next; }
```

I am making some mistake in the not-match `(?!$ERR)` operator but I don't know how to correct it. I appreciate your inputs in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Sorry I thought regex is common between python and perl. I apologize if its not.

Comment: It's common to most popular languages these days.

Comment: Thanks, I removed python tag.

Comment: \s is a character class that represents all whitespace charaters and therefore includes \n and \t so you can simplify a little by changing (\s*\n*\t*) into (\s*).   You're also going to want to play with /s modifier to match \n in the middle of a string.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about /s modifier? Is /s same as '.' + '\n' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `(ERR|WRN)` instead of `(DBG|NOT|UNC)` and then negate it with `!`.

You can use `\s*` instead of `\s*\t*\n*` because `\s` matches any whitespace.

```
if ( ! /PRINT\((\s*)[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*(_*)(ERR|WRN)/ ) { next; }
```

**Input:**

```
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_DBG...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_NOT...
PRINT(ABC_UNC...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_ERR...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_WRN...
PRINT(ABC_ERR...
```

**One-liner:**

```
perl -nle 'if ( ! /PRINT\((\s*)[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*(_*)(ERR|WRN)/  ) { next; } print' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_ERR...
PRINT(ABC_XYZ_WRN...
PRINT(ABC_ERR...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
next unless ( /PRINT\((\s*\n*\t*)[A-Z]+_[A-Z]*(_*)(ERR|WRN)/ );
```

Comment: How about adding a little bit of explanation?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really necessary. It just negates the condition that matches ERR and WRN patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. While it works, I want to know what the right way to use the not-match operator just for learning purposes. Can you tell me how to do this without using unless?